# Flutter ButtonBar in horizontal mode doesn't seem to respect MainAxisSize

Tags: flutter

I would like to use flutter's ButtonBar due to the nice feature of automatically having a column when the device's width isn't enough. However, I'd also like to use the MainAxisSize.min, but I can't get it to use MainAxisSize.min in horizontal mode (wrt width). See example below.

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
              child: ButtonBar(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('short'),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('short'),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
              child: ButtonBar(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('loooooooooooooooooong'),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('loooooooooooooooooong'),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfcEP.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpV5q.png)

Comment: For anyone facing a similar problem, I ended up doing it some other way and have added a flutter issue regarding this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53642

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to use the `Wrap` class instead of the `ButtonBar`. You have to 
wrap the Container with a Center widget add some padding for the layout and your're god to go:

[image]

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
      child: ButtonBar(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('short'),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('short'),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Wrap(
          //alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('looooooooooooooooooooooooong'),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('looooooooooooooooooooooooong'),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: That works for this specific example, where there are only two buttons. If there are more buttons, example [short, short, looong], wrap will put the ones it can on the same row, ([short, short], [long]). What I want is either _all_ on the same row, or every button on a separate row.